How to edit and build IAR projects in Visual Studio 2022 for free?
I have a Visual Studio solution that is dependent on multiple IAR projects. How can these projects be brought into Visual Studio? This is a need for work and, while the company is willing to allow support a VS add in, it doesn't want to purchase something for all of the programmers. That means that some free VS add on is installed and configured. Any suggestions?

Perhaps you want to consider using VisualGDB in such a scenario.
They provide a tutorial on how to use the IAR ARM Compiler with Visual Studio alongside VisualGDB: https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/arm/iar/

At present, VS does not have relevant documents or instructions to guide how to use IAR projects in VS. In addition, it may be more appropriate to use VS Code to build or edit IAR projects, but some extensions must be installed. If you really want to build or edit IAR projects in VS, I suggest you report this feature request to DC, where there are many VS developers who may be able to help you:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest
It is important to note that if there are enough users submitting requests for this feature, Microsoft may process the feature request in this area, and if there are not many users submitting the feature request, Microsoft may not consider this aspect of the feature.

Thank you for your response.
In my particular use case, I have a C# project that needs to have products produced by multiple IAR projects. In an ideal world, VS would treat IAR's EWP project file like any other recognized project, but, of course, it doesn't. As a work around, I've elected to use a pre-build event to call a PowerShell script that knows how to find and build all of the IAR projects. This will allow the products produced by the IAR compiler to be consumed as required by the rest of the solution. There is one problem that I have not yet solved, how to handle Debug vs Release configuration, but that can be addressed by a minor edit of the VS project file.
Clearly, this is a hack, but it meets my needs. Oh, well. You cannot have everything. If you did, where would you put it?
